# How to prevent a DHCP Starvation attack in a wireless network

Tags: network, wifi, mac-address, dhcp, mac-spoofing

Is there any way to prevent a DHCP Starvation attack when using a **wireless network with anonymous users?**

- Port security cannot be used since maxing the number of clients that can connect on a port would block legitimate users too, which is essentially what the attacker wants to achieve in the first place.
- DHCP snooping is useless without port security since an attacker can spoof his MAC address in the Ethernet packet, as well as in the DHCP payload.

I found one source which claimed that MAC address spoofing is impossible because of the 802.11 standards, which would solve the problem, but after some further looking, I could not find any other source validating this.

Edit:

- This is not a duplicate of [How to prevent DHCP Starvation attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52670/how-to-prevent-dhcp-starvation-attack) since I already found that question before I asked mine. The difference is the "wireless network" part which makes a **huge** difference since port security is not a possible solution.
- By anonymous I do mean random people which makes mac filtering impossible too. How do public wifi spots solve this? Do they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent DHCP Starvation attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52670/how-to-prevent-dhcp-starvation-attack)

Comment: MAC filtering ? No white-listed MAC, no allocated IP. That's if by anonymous users you don't mean you allow random people to connect.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear if it wasn't already.

Comment: Hello Keanu and welcome to StackExchange. If you feel like a question is close enough to be a duplicate, but different enough to warrant its own question, then please state so in your initial question. This avoids confusion, people flagging your question as duplicate, etc.

Comment: Hello MechMK1, I've edited my question to make it clear why this is different than the other post. I'm still looking for an answer to this as I need to be able to answer this question in my thesis.